# How to sort an array of objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, object

My array does not contain any string. But its contains object references. Every object reference returns name, id, author and publisher by toString method.

```
public String toString() {
        return (name + "\n" + id + "\n" + author + "\n" + publisher + "\n");
}
```

Now I need to sort that array of objects by the name. I know how to sort, but I do not know how to extract the name from the objects and sort them.

Comment: Implement a `Comparator` and use it for sorting.

Comment: In the `Comparator` split the string and use the first element as the name.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You have two ways to do that, both use the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) utility class

1. Implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass your array along with the comparator to the [sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) which take it as second parameter.
2. Implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in the class your objects are from and pass your array to the [sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) which takes only one parameter.

**Example**

```
class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    public String name, id, author, publisher;
    public Book(String name, String id, String author, String publisher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return ("(" + name + ", " + id + ", " + author + ", " + publisher + ")");
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book o) {
        // usually toString should not be used,
        // instead one of the attributes or more in a comparator chain
        return toString().compareTo(o.toString());
    }
}

@Test
public void sortBooks() {
    Book[] books = {
            new Book("foo", "1", "author1", "pub1"),
            new Book("bar", "2", "author2", "pub2")
    };

    // 1. sort using Comparable
    Arrays.sort(books);
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(books));

    // 2. sort using comparator: sort by id
    Arrays.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Book o1, Book o2) {
            return o1.id.compareTo(o2.id);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(books));
}
```

**Output**

```
[(bar, 2, author2, pub2), (foo, 1, author1, pub1)]
[(foo, 1, author1, pub1), (bar, 2, author2, pub2)]
```

Answer (score 60):

You can try something like this:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>(){

  public int compare(Book o1, Book o2)
  {
     return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 45):

### Java 8

---

#### Using [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
Arrays.sort(myTypes, (a,b) -> a.name.compareTo(b.name));
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyType[] myTypes = {
                new MyType("John", 2, "author1", "publisher1"),
                new MyType("Marry", 298, "author2", "publisher2"),
                new MyType("David", 3, "author3", "publisher3"),
        };

        System.out.println("--- before");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myTypes));
        Arrays.sort(myTypes, (a, b) -> a.name.compareTo(b.name));
        System.out.println("--- after");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(myTypes));

    }

}
```

**MyType.java**

```
public class MyType {

    public String name;
    public int id;
    public String author;
    public String publisher;

    public MyType(String name, int id, String author, String publisher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyType{" +
                "name=" + name + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", author='" + author + '\'' +
                ", publisher='" + publisher + '\'' +
                '}' + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
--- before
[MyType{name=John', id=2, author='author1', publisher='publisher1'}
, MyType{name=Marry', id=298, author='author2', publisher='publisher2'}
, MyType{name=David', id=3, author='author3', publisher='publisher3'}
]
--- after
[MyType{name=David', id=3, author='author3', publisher='publisher3'}
, MyType{name=John', id=2, author='author1', publisher='publisher1'}
, MyType{name=Marry', id=298, author='author2', publisher='publisher2'}
]
```

---

#### Using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

```
Arrays.sort(myTypes, MyType::compareThem);
```

where `compareThem` has to be added in **MyType.java**:

```
public static int compareThem(MyType a, MyType b) {
    return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
}
```

Comment: If you want to use lambda expressions in Android Studio, you should look at this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: See [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: In the above case, instead of name , if it was id, how can we do?

Comment: I try with replacing name with id, but the error was "dereferencing not possible for int,) so i converted the int to string. Now there is no error, but it is not sorting?

Answer (score 15):

### Update for Java 8 constructs

Assuming a `Book` class with a `name` field getter, you can use `Arrays.sort` method by passing an additional `Comparator` specified using Java 8 constructs - [Comparator default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) & [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
Arrays.sort(bookArray, Comparator.comparing(Book::getName));
```

Also, it's possible to compare on multiple fields using `thenComparing` methods.

```
Arrays.sort(bookArray, Comparator.comparing(Book::getName)
      .thenComparing(Book::getAuthor))
      .thenComparingInt(Book::getId));
```

Answer (score 4):

With **Java 8**, you can use a reference method.

You could add `compare` method to your `Book` class

```java
class Book {
    public static int compare(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
}
```

And then you could do this :

```java
Arrays.sort(books, Book::compare);
```

Here is the full example:

```java
class Book {
    String name;
    String author;

    public Book(String name, String author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public static int compareBooks(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name : " + name + "\t" + "author : " + author;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book[] books = {
                new Book("Book 3", "Author 1"),
                new Book("Book 2", "Author 2"),
                new Book("Book 1", "Author 3"),
                new Book("Book 4", "Author 4")
        };
        Arrays.sort(books, Book::compareBooks);
        Arrays.asList(books).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 3):

```
 Arrays.sort(yourList,new Comparator<YourObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
        return compare(o1.getYourColumn(), o2.getYourColumn());
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
[Employee(name=John, age=25, salary=3000.0, mobile=9922001), 
 Employee(name=Ace, age=22, salary=2000.0, mobile=5924001), 
 Employee(name=Keith, age=35, salary=4000.0, mobile=3924401)]
```

```java
public void whenComparing_thenSortedByName() {
    Comparator<Employee> employeeNameComparator
            = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);
    Arrays.sort(employees, employeeNameComparator);
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(employees, sortedEmployeesByName));
}
```

result

```
[Employee(name=Ace, age=22, salary=2000.0, mobile=5924001), 
 Employee(name=John, age=25, salary=3000.0, mobile=9922001), 
 Employee(name=Keith, age=35, salary=4000.0, mobile=3924401)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to sort an array of objects on an arbitrary value.  Since compareTo() always uses the same information about the instance, you might want to use a different technique.  One way is to use a standard sorting algorithm.  Let's say you have an array of books and you want to sort them on their height, which is stored as an int and accessible through the method getHeight().  Here's how you could sort the books in your array. (If you don't want to change the original array, simply make a copy and sort that.)

```
`int tallest; // the index of tallest book found thus far
 Book temp; // used in the swap
 for(int a = 0; a < booksArray.length - 1; a++) {
   tallest = a; // reset tallest to current index
   // start inner loop at next index
   for(int b = a + 1; b < booksArray.length; b++)
     // check if the book at this index is taller than the
     // tallest found thus far
     if(booksArray[b].getHeight() > booksArray[tallest].getHeight())
       tallest = b;
   // once inner loop is complete, swap the tallest book found with
   // the one at the current index of the outer loop
   temp = booksArray[a];
   booksArray[a] = booksArray[tallest];
   booksArray[tallest] = temp;
 }`
```

When this code is done, the array of Book object will be sorted by height in descending order--an interior designer's dream!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the "Comparable" interface on a class whose objects you want to compare.

And also implement the "compareTo" method in that.

Add the instances of the class in an ArrayList

Then the "java.utils.Collections.sort()" method will do the necessary magic.

Here's--->(https://deva-codes.herokuapp.com/CompareOnTwoKeys) a working example where objects are sorted based on two keys first by the id and then by name.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example of `Book` class and build a list of book objects:-

```java
public class Book {
  String name;
  String author;
  double rating;
}

Book book1 = new Book("book1", "author1", 3.0);
Book book2 = new Book("book2", "author2", 5);
Book book3 = new Book("book3", "author1", 4.0);
Book book4 = new Book("book4", "author2", 2.5);
Book book5 = new Book("book5", "author1", 4.0);

List<Book> library = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3, book4, book5);
```

We can sort a list of objects using `Comparator.comparing()`. We can also chain it with `.thenComparing()` to sort by multiple fields. Let's look at examples:-

```java
// Sort in ascending order
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparing(Book::getAuthor));
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparingDouble(Book::getRating));

// Sort in descending order
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparing(Book::getAuthor).reversed());
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparingDouble(Book::getRating).reversed());

// Sort by multiple fields in ascending order
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparing(Book::getAuthor)
            .thenComparingDouble(Book::getRating)
            .thenComparing(Book::getName));

// Sort by multiple fields in ascending then descending order
Collections.sort(library, Comparator.comparing(Book::getAuthor)
        .thenComparing((b1, b2) -> Double.compare(b2.getRating(), b1.getRating()))
        .thenComparing((b1, b2) -> b2.getName().compareTo(b1.getName())));
```

> Source: [CodingNConcepts](https://codingnconcepts.com/java/sort-array-list-of-object-in-java/)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private int sid;
    private String sname;

    public Student(int sid, String sname) {
        super();
        this.sid = sid;
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    public int getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(int sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }

    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [sid=" + sid + ", sname=" + sname + "]";
    }

    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if (this.getSname().compareTo(o.getSname()) > 1) {
            return toString().compareTo(o.getSname());
        } else if (this.getSname().compareTo(o.getSname()) < 1) {
            return toString().compareTo(o.getSname());
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: adding sort check in Test class in below application

Answer (score -2):

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> str = new ArrayList<Student>();
        str.add(new Student(101, "aaa"));
        str.add(new Student(104, "bbb"));
        str.add(new Student(103, "ccc"));
        str.add(new Student(105, "ddd"));
        str.add(new Student(104, "eee"));
        str.add(new Student(102, "fff"));

        Collections.sort(str);
        for (Student student : str) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
}
```