# Ordering array by a property in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects in Java. Let's say `Product products[]`.

Each of those products have a price, for example, `product.getPrice()`.

What's the best way I can order that product array by the price so I can call, `products[0]` for the most expensive product and `products[products.length-1]` for the least expensive?

Comment: Sort `products` by the price of each product via `Arrays.sort()`

Comment: Define a class that implements `Comparator<Product>` and use `Arrays.sort()` or use any sorted collection.

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Have `Product` implement `Comparable`. Then you can sort it.

Comment: @SJuan76 could you provide me with an example? I'm not great with Java

Comment: You'll get better at it when you try it by yourself. It is all in the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895915/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-in-java might be better since you're using an `Array` rather than an `ArrayList`

Comment: why would someone vote to close because its unclear what they're asking. It seems quite clear to me what the question is.

Comment: @ug_ yes, it is a "give me the code" question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(products, new Comparator<Product>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
        if (p1.getPrice() > p2.getPrice()) return -1;
        if (p1.getPrice() < p2.getPrice()) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: An equivalent way to return: `return p2.getPrice() - p1.getPrice();` for descending, like above. Or, `return p1.getPrice() - p2.getPrice();` for ascending prices. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an `ArrayList` to do this. Index them in order from most expensive to least expensive using a for loop, like this:

```
ArrayList products = new ArrayList();
final int MAX_PRICE = 9999; // Or whatever the maximum price should be
for (int i = MAX_PRICE, i > 0, i--) {
    if (product.getPrice() == i) {
        products.add(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: If he is dealing with prices then getPrice() most likely returns a double. Array.sort() is the best option IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **Comparable interface** to override **compareTo** method with template T as Products.
Then use the following code,

```
Collections.sort(products);
```

You can always use Oracle docs for knowing about Comparable Interface at [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)