# How to get sorted array with file paths android?

Tags: android, file

I would like to get array with sorted filePaths. I have managed to get sorted array with filenames like this:

```
fileList.addAll(Arrays.asList(curFolder.list()));
Collections.sort(fileList);
```

and I know about such way of getting file paths:

```
folder.listFiles()
```

I also know that I can sort all file paths by name or date but I didn't manage to do it. In the end I will add this paths to my recyclerView adapter:

```
FileManagerAdapter fileManagerAdapter = new FileManagerAdapter(this, (ArrayList<String>) fileList, curFolder.listFiles());
```

maybe I have to get file path at adapter or what? I hope you will help me :)

Comment: And Whats your question here ? Which part is problematic ? Sorting or Adapter ?

Comment: @ADM, my problem is that I can't sort File[] by names like my filelist array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895915/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-in-java

Comment: @ADM, can you explain this question please, because I can't still understand how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

```
File[] files = curFolder.listFiles();

Arrays.sort(files, (f1, f2) -> {
if (f1.isDirectory() && !f2.isDirectory()) {
return -1;
} else if (!f1.isDirectory() && f2.isDirectory()) {
return 1;
} else {
return f1.compareTo(f2);
}
});
```

and as a result:

```
[/storage/emulated/0/Alarms, /storage/emulated/0/Android, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM, /storage/emulated/0/Download, /storage/emulated/0/Jobnetzwerk, /storage/emulated/0/Movies, /storage/emulated/0/Music, /storage/emulated/0/Notifications, /storage/emulated/0/Pictures, /storage/emulated/0/Podcasts, /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones]
```