# Sorting arrays descending

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've recently learned how to sort arrays in ascending order with this code in Java;

```
int swapIndex,temp; 
for(int index=0; index<=array.length-2; index++) { 
    swapIndex = index; 
    for(int i=index+1; i<=array.length-1; i++) 
       if(array[i]<array[swapIndex]) swapIndex = i; 
    temp = array[index]; array[index] = array[swapIndex]; 
    array[swapIndex] = temp; 
  } 
}
```

Can somebody please tell me how to I can use this code but sort in descending order?
Best regards

Comment: Have you tried changing `<` to `>` in `if`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use something like this instead?

```
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: There is no such method for primitive arrays.

Comment: I'm not calling method from a primitive array. I'm calling it from the java.utils.Arrays class

Comment: Yes, and java.util.Arrays has no such method that takes a primitive array and a Comparator (because Comparator only works for Objects).

Comment: Oh, yes your right. Then I guess he could convert the int[] to an Integer[] and then do some simple work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just flip the sign in your if statement

```
int swapIndex,temp; 
for(int index=0; index<=array.length-2; index++) { 
    swapIndex = index; 
    for(int i=index+1; i<=array.length-1; i++) 
       if(array[i] > array[swapIndex]) swapIndex = i; //change the sign
    temp = array[index]; array[index] = array[swapIndex]; 
    array[swapIndex] = temp; 
  } 
}
```

This way, you're only swapping if the element at i is greater than the one at swapIndex, so the smaller numbers get moved further to the right.