# how to sort 2 arrays and compare values in it

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays i want to sort those arrays and compare it

```
var A = [1,5,8,0,9];
var B = [5,9,0,1,8];
for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)
{
if(A[i] == B[i]){message}else{Fail}
```

I want to sort those arrays and then compare the values

Comment: Thing you are doing is far away from sort

Comment: So, which part do you have trouble with? Sorting or [comparing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)?

Comment: You can calll the `sort` method on an array: `A.sort()`. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: i tried .sort , it dint work

Comment: I want to sort both arrays

Comment: BTW people, the question is bad, but it's not "unclear what you're asking". The question is straight-forward but lacks effort.

Comment: So? Why don't you sort them then? Lack of documentation/examples out there?

Comment: I wrote some code , its not the actual code

Comment: Come one, you've asked over 20 questions here already, you should know the deal by now: *provide more info!* What did you try _exactly_? What do you expect to happen? What is happening? Remember: the quality of answers is almost directly proportional to the quality of the question: if you don't put any effort in your question, why should we put effort into answering it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array Sort descending?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `sort` method on an array:

```js
var A = [1, 5, 8, 0, 9];
var B = [5, 9, 0, 1, 8];
A.sort()
B.sort()
for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  if (A[i] == B[i]) {
    document.write(A[i] + ' and ' + B[i] + ' are identical' + '<br>')
  } else {
    document.write('fail')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***sort()*** for this . [Arary sort()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)
I cant properly understand whats the aim behind the comparison.SO make necessary changes.

```
var A = [1,5,8,0,9];
A.sort();
var B = [5,9,0,1,8];
B.sort();

for(i=0;i<A.length;i++)
{
     if(A[i] == B[i])
      {
            message
      }
      else 
      {
             Fail
      }
}
```