# Sort int[] array big to small

Tags: java, arrays, int

I want to sort the numbers so that the output is: [12,9,8,7,5,4,3,1]
Please help ;)

```
int[] array = new int[]{8,5,3,7,9,12,4,1};
int biggest = 0;
for (int i =0; i<array.length;i++){
    if(array[i]>biggest){
        biggest = array[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(biggest); //Outputs 12
```

Comment: You mean you want to sort the array?

Comment: binary search method, but of course the array has to be sorted first?

Comment: JDK 8 and lambdas make it easy.

Comment: Yes lol, i want to sort the array :D

Comment: Collections.sort is your friend.

Comment: Please edit the question and/or title, it is vague and confusing

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Java Array Sort descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int[] array = new int[]{8,5,3,7,9,12,4,1};
    Arrays.sort(array);
    for (int i =array.length -1; i>=0;i--){
      System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

And with streams:

```
int[] array = new int[]{8,5,3,7,9,12,4,1};
Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: does this algorithm answer the authors questions  of "Shortest way to find the biggest integer in a row in a list[JAVA]"...... ?

Comment: This works, but idk if this is the shortes but thanks m8

Comment: @Os. I this this is exactly what he wants, by described output example. But yes, the question is a bit... confusing?

Comment: @iMysak alright, as long as the author is happy, then all good. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use streams in java 8:

```
int[] array = new int[]{8,5,3,7,9,12,4,1};
int max = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Only prints out 12 instead of the whole row

Comment: @luukcollin your questions says "Shortest way to find the biggest integer in a row in a list[JAVA]" hence he has provided that algorithm for you

Answer (score 0):

Use the bubble sort to organize the array:

```
int a, b, t;
int size = array.length;

for(a=1; a < size; a++)
    for(b=size-1; b >= a; b--){
        if(array[b-1] > array[b]){ //If out of order
           t = array[b-1];
           array[b-1] = array[b];
           array[b] = t;
          }
   }
```

then reverse the order so it's highest to lowest:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++)
    {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
        array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
```