# no suitable method found for sort, inference array variable has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, arrays

The function tries to transform the array into a pendulum form.
Like the input is:

```
1 3 2 5 4
```

The answer should be:

```
5 3 1 2 4
```

The minimum is in between.

```
public static void printPendulum(int[] arr, int n){
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int noOfRotations = n/2;
    for(int i=0;i<noOfRotations;i++){
        int temp = arr[n-1];
        for(int j=n-1;j>0;j--){
            arr[j] = arr[j-1];
        }
        arr[0] = temp;
    }
    int temparr[] = new int[noOfRotations-1];
    for(int i=0;i<noOfRotations-1;i++)
        temparr[i] = arr[i];
    Comparator<Integer> comp = Collections.reverseOrder();     
    Arrays.sort(temparr, comp);
    for(int i=0;i<noOfRotations-1;i++)
        arr[i] = temparr[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();     
}
```

The compilation error is as follows:

```
    prog.java:36: error: no suitable method found for sort(int[],Comparator<Integer>)
        Arrays.sort(temparr, comp);
              ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        upper bounds: Integer,Object)
    method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array Sort descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Integer temparr[] = new Integer[noOfRotations-1];
```

instead

```
int temparr[] = new int[noOfRotations-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

**There is no signature with a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for arrays of primitives.**

For instance, the signatures for an `int[]` array are:

```
sort(int[] a)
sort(int[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
```

The one you are trying to use looks like:

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

So you need to pass **an `Integer[]`**, not an `int[]`:

```
Integer[] boxedArray = Arrays.stream(temparr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
Arrays.sort(boxedArray, comp);
```