# I am sorting my array in reverse order, but it seems something is wrong with collections

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, bubble-sort

This is my code:

```
public void p10(int a, int b, int c){
    int[] nums = new int[] {a, b, c};
    Arrays.sort(nums, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

What could be the problem that it doesn't work and it gives an error? Error states that:

> java: no suitable method found for sort(int[],java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>)
> method java.util.Arrays.sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
> (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: int
> upper bounds: java.lang.Object)
> method java.util.Arrays.sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
> (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))

Comment: [Java Array Sort descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56673782)

Answer (score 1):

int[] is a primitive array that doesn't work with comparators, so you will need to convert it to an array of `Integer`s before doing the sorting:

```java
public void p10(int a, int b, int c){
    Integer[] nums = new Integer[] {a, b, c};
    Arrays.sort(nums, Collections.reverseOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```

`Integer` is just a wrapper object around `int`, which the java compiler can seamlessly inline with other math operations. Using an `Integer` is functionally (almost) the same as using a raw `int`.